# Run celery tasks concurrently using pytest

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, celery, celery-task

I'm trying to integration test a concurrent celery task in my Django app. I want the task to actually run concurrently on a worker during the pytest integration test but I'm having trouble making that work.

Let's say I have the following basic celery task:

```
@shared_task
def sleep_task(secs):
    print(f"Sleeping for {secs} seconds...")
    for i in range(secs):
        time.sleep(i)
        print(f"\t{i + 1}")
    return "DONE"
```

Running the task concurrently in a script works fine:

```
# script
sleep_task.delay(3)
sleep_task.delay(3)

# output
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

However, I can't duplicate this asynchronous behavior in a unit test. Within `conftest.py` I setup the broker and the result backend:

```
import pytest

pytest_plugins = ("celery.contrib.pytest",)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def celery_config():
    return {"broker_url": "memory://", "result_backend": "rpc://"}
```

And here is my unit test. `celery_session_app` and `celery_session_worker` sets up the celery app and worker used for testing ([docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/testing.html)):

```
def test_concurrent_sleep_tasks(celery_session_app, celery_session_worker):
    sleep_task.delay(3)
    sleep_task.delay(3)

# output
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
1
2
3
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
1
2
3
```

It appears the tasks are running synchronously. Is there anyway to run the tasks asynchronously?

Comment: I would assume that the problem is with `time.sleep(3)` which is blocking the entire execution of the script. Can you switch to `asyncio.sleep(3)` that is non-blocking and see if that would work?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[celery_session_worker](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/7288147d65a32b726869ed887d99e4bfd8c070e2/celery/contrib/pytest.py#L76) fixture is starting a [celery worker](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/7288147d65a32b726869ed887d99e4bfd8c070e2/celery/contrib/testing/worker.py#L56) with concurrency of 1. This is hardcoded in celery.contrib and it is not configurable currently. Since concurrency is 1, it will process only 1 task at a time.

An alternate solution is to write your own fixture to start a worker with a concurrency of 2 or more.

Comment: Wrote my own worker fixture with concurrency set to 2 but no luck. Looks like I have to go the normal route by spinning up a queue and worker during my pytest run to get this to work, which isn't too bad.

Comment: Could you elaborate or provide some code snippets for your solution? I'm also wanting to test functions which invoke concurrent celery tasks however have only been able to run them sequentially with .run instead of .delay. Using .delay seems to have the effect of only running the task after the test (pytest) has finished running.